# Move to top inner table

Tags: html, css

How I close this gap between the inner table and the main table cell?

https://jsfiddle.net/w7eekbcL/2/

```
<td>
         <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-family:verdana; color:#424242">main list</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">list</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">&bull; one</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">&bull; second</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">&bull; thurd</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </td>
```

For example I tried to use text-aligment but the result is the same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to the `td` that contains the table.